# Edge endpoints when automating node connections with Tikz/automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, automata, edge

I'm trying to draw a Markov chain. As I have 11 states, I tried to automate the declaration of states as well as the edges in a for loop. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', auto, semithick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,thick,text=black]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,10}
    {
        \node[state] (\i) at (\i*2,0) {\i};
        \path (\i) edge[loop above] node{0.1} (\i);
    }

    \foreach \i in {0,...,9}
    {
        \pgfmathparse{\i+1}; % result goes into --> \pgfmathresult
        \path (\i) edge node{0.3} (\pgfmathresult);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

As you see, the end points of the horizontal edges go to the "east" of the target state. Ideally, I would want them to go to "west". On the other hand, if I write the edges one by one manually, I get a much better result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', auto, semithick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,thick,text=black]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,10}
    {
        \node[state] (\i) at (\i*2,0) {\i};
        \path (\i) edge[loop above] node{0.1} (\i);
    }
    \path (0) edge node{0.3} (1);
    \path (1) edge node{0.3} (2);
    \path (2) edge node{0.3} (3);
    \path (3) edge node{0.3} (4);
    \path (4) edge node{0.3} (5);
    \path (5) edge node{0.3} (6);
    \path (6) edge node{0.3} (7);
    \path (7) edge node{0.3} (8);
    \path (8) edge node{0.3} (9);
    \path (9) edge node{0.3} (10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What exactly is happening here? Why do the two behave differently? Am I doing something wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do not use `tikzstyle` - it is deprecated.

Comment: I just notice, that you use the tikzlibrary `arrows`. -do not do that -it is deprecated. -see my answer for alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal place from `pgfmathparse` is interpreted as an angle in the coordinate. -so you need an integer like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{automata, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every state/.style={fill=white, thick}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >={Stealth[round]}, auto, semithick]
\foreach \i in {0,...,10}{
\node[state] (\i) at (\i*2,0) {\i};
\draw (\i) edge[loop above] node{0.1} (\i);
}
\foreach \i in {0,...,9}{
\pgfmathparse{int(\i+1)}
\draw (\i) edge node{0.3} (\pgfmathresult);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Nodes in a line connected by arrows]

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know the (NodeName.Angle) format. That is also quite useful to know beyond this question.